# Dropbox creation of folder with same name as non synced folder

Tags: sync, dropbox

I had a folder called WWW in my dropbox root which I decided not to sync with install around 6 months ago, since then I have evidently created a new WWW folder in dropbox.

Now I cannot see it in dropbox and have just formatted and re-installed Windows, have I lost that folder  now? When I view folders in dropbox I see that old version of WWW and nothing additional even when I view deleted folders!

Desperate now.

Comment: If you check the WWW folder with select sync, it will be downloaded to your computer with the folder rename to say there is a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

If you stopped syncing the folder to dropbox months ago, then dropbox should not have a copy after then, right? The only copy on dropbox should be months old, isn't that how dropbox should work? I think you could check the web interface for dropbox and that should show everything, in case it's still there, regardless of your current hard drive setup.

And it's the new version (that was reformatted along with your old Windows) you want back? If there was a backup of your drive before reformatting it, that would be the best place to recover the files.

2nd best: you may still be able to recover them with an undelete or data recovery tool (like `testdisk` perhaps) that is if you haven't overwritten them on the HD yet.